# Multiple authors for blogpost

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am a bit stuck on trying to solve this

So I have a webapp, and decided to add a blog section using wagtail. This means I have quite a few pages and models already preexisting, that I do not want to touch, as well as some users already. I am aware of the `owner` field in the base `Page` class, but can't see a way to extend to into a m2m field.

To achieve this, I have created a custom user model at `users.User`. For blog community purposes, I wanted to add the option of picing an avatar and setting a biography, so I added those two (avatar and bio are newly added fields)

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name of User as displayed to other users"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    avatar = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

Then I have a classic Blogpost page, with title, body streamfield etc... However, I am trying to replace something where you can add multiple post editors, and each of them has edit rights. So I tried something like this:

First an orderable since I need many2many:

```
class PostAuthorsOrderable(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey("blog.BlogPost", related_name="post_authors")
    author = models.ForeignKey("users.User",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    panels = [
       SnippetChooserPanel("author"),
    ]
```

And then in the BlogPost page itself:

```
class BlogPost(Page):
    ...
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                InlinePanel("post_authors", label="Author", min_num=1, max_num=4)
            ],
            heading="Authors (don't forget to add yourself!)"
        ),
        ...
    ]
```

However this is not working, any idea on how to achieve this? I do get the proper form in the wagtail admin, but I get an error. It tries to do a callback, presumable to find a list of all possible users to select, but it is giving a 404, presumably because the user is not registered as a snippet.

Before I try registering the user as a snippet, I wanted to get a second opinion here, because that feels a bit wrong somehow

PS: bonuspoints if you can also tell me how I can get a widget in the editor to just select authors by autocompleting their names into a text field , a bit like this: [example](https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Dynamic-Autocomplete-Multi-select-Plugin-With-jQuery-magicsearch.jpg)

EDIT: When I click the button to add an Author, nothing happens, all I can see is a 404 in the console

```
172.19.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2021 15:26:09] "GET /admin/snippets/choose/users/user/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
Not Found: /admin/snippets/choose/users/user/
```

Comment: "I do get the proper form in the wagtail admin, but I get an error." - please give us the error message, including the full traceback.

Comment: @gasman I added an edit with what I see in the console. Since its a 404, there is no traceback. But you see in the URL its trying to find a snippet, but user.User is not registered as a snippet. Somehow it feels wrong to add my user model as a snippet...

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options you could take:

1. Are you sure you need to use a User model for this? If this is just being used to attach a name / photo / bio to a blog post, it could potentially just be a plain Django model registered as a snippet, separate to your user accounts.
2. You could register the user model as a snippet, as you suggest, and this would allow `SnippetChooserPanel` to work - the only negative side effect is that it would add an 'edit' view for users under the Snippets menu that probably wouldn't be fully functional due to the custom logic that exists on user models (for example, it would most likely offer an encrypted password field rather than a human-usable one). You can safely ignore this (and it won't be shown to non-superusers unless you explicitly give them permission for it under Settings -> Groups).
3. There are a few third-party add-ons for Wagtail that provide a chooser for non-Snippet models - see [wagtailmodelchooser](https://github.com/neon-jungle/wagtailmodelchooser) and [wagtail-generic-chooser](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-generic-chooser).